# Modifying Python DataFrame rows with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to modify a python pandas dataframe. Consider

```
Id    Col
1     a
2     a
3     p
3     sp
4     n
4     sn
5     b
6     c
```

is my dataframe. Ids 3 and 4 appear twice. For rows having Id 3, Col has values p and sp. Similarly for Id 4 we see values n and sn in Col. I want to remove row having Col as p for Id 3 and row having Col as n for Id 4. So i wnat my dataframe to look like

```
Id    Col
1     a
2     a
3     sp
4     sn
5     b
6     c
```

so basically, here is what i need to do

1. Check if ther are any duplicates. Lets assume that the duplicates only occur in pairs and not in triples or more.
2. Then if the value of the Col is same, then we keep only one such row.
3. If the values in the Col are p and sp, i want to keep the row that has sp.
4. If the values in the Col are n and sn, i want to keep the row that has sn.

how can i achieve this?

**EDIT**

actually, ideally i would need to check before deciding which row to drop. Lets say i know that there are multiple rows with Id 3 and the corresponding values of Col are

```
p
sp
```

now i want to collect these values in a list as

```
['p','sp']
```

and send it to a function like

```
def giveMeBest(paramList):

   bestVal = ""

   for param in paramList:
    '''
    some logic goes here
   '''
   return bestVal
```

then i only keep the row which has value bestVal in Col. Note that this will also allow me to handle any number of duplicates.

**EDIT2**

Thanks rurp for the answer. I just one last request. I am trying to clean up my data frame by doing the following

```
for x in result:

        resVal = getVal(x[1])

        '''
        getVal returns the appropriate  value that i want to be set in 
        my dataframe. Note that x[1] will denote the array of duplicate values in Col

        '''

        resData = resData[(resData.Id == x[0]) & (resData.Col!=resVal)]
```

but this still does not delete the rows

```
print(resData[resData.Id==3])

Id Col
3  p
3  sp
```

i even tried

```
resData = resData.drop(resData[(resData.Id == int(x[0])) & (resData.Col!=resSent)].index)
```

but it still shows the duplicate row.

how can i drop multiple rows from my data frame ?

**Solved dropping rows**

here is how i did it

```
idx = []
for x in result:

    resVal = getVal(x[1])

    idx.append(resData[(resData.Id == x[0]) & (resData.Col!= resVal)].index.tolist())
```

and then, just

```
for j in idx:
    resData = resData.drop(j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list of tuples containing each 'Id' value that occurs more than once and a list of the corresponding values in 'Col'. Those values could then be passed in to your function to determine which to remove.

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6]
cols = ['a', 'a', 'p', 'sp', 'n', 'sn', 'b', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':ids, 'Col':cols})

counts = df['Id'].value_counts()
values = [x for x in counts.index if counts[x]>1]
result = []
for e in values:
    vals = df[df['Id'] == e].Col.value_counts().index.values
    result.append((e, vals))
```

This give you

```
for n in result:
    print n

(4, array(['n', 'sn'], dtype=object))
(3, array(['sp', 'p'], dtype=object))
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: perfect ! exactly what i needed :) now i can run my logic and cleanup the data. thanks a lot :)

Comment: lastly, what would be the efficient way to delete the rows now? i guess a double loop is the most straightforward

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `s`s were always last you could use drop_duplicates:

```
In [11]: df.drop_duplicates(take_last=True, subset=["Col"])
Out[11]:
   Id Col
1   2   a
2   3   p
3   3  sp
4   4   n
5   4  sn
6   5   b
7   6   c
```

If not sort them so they are. The easiest way is to pull out a column of `is_s` (e.g. `.str.startswith("s")`) and sorting by that before dropping duplicates.

Comment: thanks ! really nice suggestion. please see the edit, as i think i need something more specific